# can you run iis on Microsoft Windows Small Business Server 2011 Essentials?

Tags: windows-sbs

Microsoft Windows Small Business Server 2011 Essentials looks like a good option to go in our scenario.  But IIS is an requirement.  Can the Essentials edition run IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all the SBS editions have included IIS.

Link here.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Windows-Small-Business-Server/editions.aspx

And here.

[image]

Comment: thank you.  I looked at this exact table before I raised the question.  Not sure how I missed that!!

Comment: @ravi: I figure you missed it because not everyone thinks of IIS as "Network Infrastructure". Most people only think DNS and DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that being SBS, IIS was already a part of the core. Seeing as it's designed to run Remote Web Workplace and OWA. So I would say yes.